# Using @Html.TextBoxFor with ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

A quick question:

So, I am developing a small MVC/C# application and I am using ViewModel to pass data to my view. The ViewModel is actually a combination of 3 Models.

My Models:

```
public class Sourcing_ProfileSourcingAreas
{
    public string Area { get; set; }

    public string Details { get; set; }
}


public class DefCountry
{
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class SourcingIndex
{
    public List<DefCountry> CountryLst { get; set; }

    public List<Sourcing_ProfileSourcingAreas> AreaLst { get; set; }
}
```

On my view, I put this line at the top `@model SourcingIndex` to declare that I will be using this ViewModel

I also was easily able to specify which model I want to display by using `foreach` loop, for example:

```
@foreach (Sourcing_ProfileSourcingAreas area in Model.AreaLst)
    {
          <tr>
              <td>@area.Area</td>
              <td>@area.Details</td>                  
          </tr>           
    }
```

And

```
@foreach (DefCountry ctry in Model.CountryLst)
{
    <option>@ctry.CountryName</option>
}
```

However, I am not able to create `@Html.TextBox` and assign it to a specific property in a model!

If possible, I want it to be somthing like this: `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AreaLst.Area)`

Thank you

Comment: the trick to doing this is to use a `for` loop not a `foreach` loop and then access the List using an indexer `[0]`, `[1]`, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what "I am not able to create" . Is there a run-time error? It could be something to do with Lazy-Loading vs not using .Include() for EF in your controller code.

Comment: I see, it seem that I need the foreach loop in order to achieve my goal

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) for how to use a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate` to generate form controls for a collection. But since you editing data, do not use data models inside a view model - create view models for each collection object

Comment: @StephenMuecke would you please give me an example? Thanks

Comment: My previous comment includes a link with examples

Comment: I will look at the link. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a weird quirk about Razor. If you try and access the objects in a `foreach` loop it struggles to resolve where in the model it is. You need to use this syntax:

```
@for (int x = 0; x < Model.CountryLst.Count(); x++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.CountryLst[x].CountryName)
}
```

this should produce an input something like

```
<input name="countryLst[1].CountryName"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.CountryLst.Count(); i++)
{
    <text>@Html.TextBoxFor(p=>Model.CountryLst[i].CountryCode)</text>
}
```